# "I am from" vs. "I am with"

Tags: differences, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I want to say that I work for Company A or represent it. I see 2 ways to express this:

- I am **from** Company A
- I am **with** Company A

Which way is correct one? What are other ways to say it?

Specifically, I am using it as username in e-mails to distinguish my e-mails from others that used simply name so recipent of my e-mail sees it in their inbox before opening e-mail.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would say:

- I am with Microsoft.
- I work at Microsoft.

If you previously worked at Microsoft...

- I came from Microsoft.
- I worked at Microsoft.

Note:  After seeing screenshot, I would definitely use at or with.  I think it is best to use 'with' since it properly identifies yourself as an employee instead of being at their location.

Comment: If you turned up at a persons door as part of a work-related process (checking their electricity meter, installing curtains, whatever) then 'I'm from Company A' would be perfectly valid.

Comment: @Sam - maybe valid but 'I'm with Company A' is better and less ambiguous.

Comment: I am actually using it as my e-mail username like that: "John from Microsoft" so I appear like that in recipent inbox before they open e-mail. I guess that in that case "John with Microsoft" is still better?

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd I agree that identifying yourself as with is more generally useful and less ambiguous. I was just pointing out a common use of the form you hadn't addressed. It is used frequently in the UK in the context I outlined.

Comment: @Sam - I agree it is common to hear, especially when someone does knock at your door to do work.

Comment: @Rafal in the context of an email, personally I would give my name and then underneath my title/company/contact details as a standard footer to all official emails. I wouldn't include my corporate affiliation in my username. If I did I would probably go with Company_MyName e.g. Microsoft_John

Comment: @Sam - I agree.  Company affiliation is usually something in the signature of an email.  If you are formally introducing yourself, 'I would like to introduce myself.  I am with Microsoft and have been assigned to your account.'  But normally it is just part of your signature...

Comment: Just added screenshot to clarify what I mean. I realize it is not common, but that is the point.

Comment: _I came from Microsoft_ is a little ambiguous don't you think? If John showed up at your doorstep and said _Hi, I'm John, I came from Microsoft and am here to install stuff on your computer_ what company are you most likely to think he currently works at?

Comment: @Frank - Anyone that says 'I come from Microsoft' isn't getting in my door!

Comment: @Rafal any mention of company affiliation in that context with a personal name attached is likely to result in unsought deletes due to suspicion of overly protested legitimacy (regardless of actual legitimacy). If you are acting in an official role, I would use that role's office as the name of the email account e.g. 'HR@microsoft.com, TechSupport@microsoft.com, Sales@microsoft.com

Comment: ha ha (and a little bit more)

Comment: "I'm from CompanyName" generally implies that you are currently working on behest of CompanyName. "I'm with CompanyName" remains true regardless of whether you're on the clock. "I'm with Microsoft, so let me fix your computer." does not suggest (assuming you're telling the truth) that you are making the offer because Microsoft wants you to. Rather, you're using your employment at Microsoft to try to lend credence to your claim to have the skills to fix computers.